# Best way to create TCP Reverse Tunnel

Tags: linux, networking, reverse-tunnel

So, here is the network setup:

```
                                                    +
    +--------+     +--------+     +--------+        |      +--------+     +--------+     +--------+
    | Client |     | Client |     | Client |        |      | Client |     | Client |     | Client |
    +--------+     +--------+     +--------+        |      +--------+     +--------+     +--------+
    |              |              |                 |      |              |              |
    |              |              |                 |      |              |              |
    |              v              |                 |      |              v              |
    +----------->+------------+<--+                 |      +----------->+------------+<--+
                 |VPS Instance|                     |                   |VPS Instance|
    +------------+------------+                     |                   +------------+
    |                         ^                     |                                ^
    |                         |                     |                                |
    |                         |              +---------->                            |
    |                         |              +---------->                            |
    |                         |              +---------->         Now a persistant two way connection
    |                     Initial Conn.             |                                |
    |                         |                     |               for tunneling client connections back
    |                         |                     |                                |
    |         For setting up a|tunnel/reverse proxy.|               to the home server.
    |                         |                     |                                |
    |                         |                     |                                |
HS Inaccessibible             |                     |                                |
    |                         |                     |                                |
    |                         |                     |                                |
    v      ISP Firewall/NAT   |                     |             ISP Firewall/NAT   |
 +----------------------------|------+              |   +----------------------------|------+
 |                            |      |              |   |                            |      |
 |          +-------------+---+      |              |   |          +-------------+<--+      |
 |          | Home Server |          |              |   |          | Home Server |          |
 |          +-------------+          |              |   |          +-------------+          |
 +-----------------------------------+              +   +-----------------------------------+
```

It also, basically, explains what I want to accomplish. I have an inaccessible server that I want to make accessible by tunneling traffic to an accessible server. Since one of the servers is inaccessible, the tunnel cannot be passive; it must be an active connection initiated by the inaccessible one.

How can this be done? Is there a way to do this with `iptables` and some combination of tunnel interfaces?

Some basic searching leads me to reverse SSH tunnels, tunnel interfaces (admittedly, I couldn't find accessible documentation on more than a high level overview which was *too* high level), and VPN software.

- A reverse SSH tunnel seems unnecessary since it doesn't need to be secured and the process running on the serve will be fairly resource intensive already and I don't want to burden it with encryption and compression.
- Tunnel interfaces: I really couldn't find a sufficiently accessible and low-level documentation that would have the shape I wanted while being at a point I would understand it.
- VPN software exposes the whole network (right?), while I really only want to forward select ports. And, frankly, it just seems to complicated most of the time.

Now, I've actually found a program to do this ([PortFusion](https://github.com/corsis/PortFusion)), I just haven't had the chance to test it's performance. Further, I feel like there should be a native way to do this on Linux, I just can't seem to find results for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've done this.  Install openvpn server on the VPS.  Configure the home box as a client.  OpenVPN will allow client-to-client connections.

You can either change the static routing on the other side of the VPS so it can send traffic to your home box, or install the VPN client on your other three machines.  The first example is harder to set up but easier to maintain.

Comment: I'm accepting this, but I still think there should be a better way...

Comment: The use of a VPN solution frees you from the hassle of worrying about specific ports being opened.  I have Windows and Linux hosts in my home (about 20), my office (five more), at two of Linode's data centers (two more), and at one of DigitalOcean's data centers (ten more).  Lots of applications talking to one another.  I'd go bonkers with a port-forwarding approach.  With OpenVPN, each box is on a seamless internal network.